# VBA execute function with several quotation marks in parameters cmd.exe

Tags: vba, function

Here is a syntax error. How to properly run the ShellWait function? I care about double quotes being used. The boolean parameter should be able to be changed to false. I do not use VBA every day so I am asking for an example if you can.

```
Sub ShellWait(fName As String, Optional showWindow As Boolean = True)
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.Run fName, -showWindow, True
End Sub

Private Sub Document_close()
    ShellWait "cmd /c echo ^<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10"^> && echo '"hello"' "
    ' ^the above code does not work
    ShellWait "cmd /c echo '"hello"' "
    ' ^the above code does not work, syntax error
    ShellWait (cmd /c echo '"hello"')
    ' ^the above code does not work, syntax error
End Sub
```

Comment: So what isn't working with the above? And what should happen?

Comment: `ShellWait "cmd /c echo ^<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10"^> && echo '"hello"' "`

Comment: I can execute `ShellWait "cmd /c cd %tmp% && echo hello > tmpfile && pause"` but in this case, the quotes do not work. I tried to replace it with `ShellWait()` with no effect.

Comment: The window `cmd.exe` should open with the words `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">` and `'"hello"'`

Comment: But not the same as /K ? i.e. ShellWait "cmd /K echo ^<meta http-equiv=""x-ua-compatible"" content=""IE=10""^> && echo '""hello""' " , I guess you want to it to close without user input?

Comment: the above example works, add a answer and i will mark it as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following

```
ShellWait "cmd /K echo ^<meta http-equiv=""x-ua-compatible"" content=""IE=10""^> && echo '""hello""' "
```